# How to save a Dataframe into an excel sheet without deleting other sheets?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am triyng to pull some data from a stock market and saving them in different excel files. Every stock trade process has different timeframes like 1m, 3m, 5m, 15m and so on..
I want to create an excel file for each stock and different sheets for each time frames.

My code creates excel file for a `stock (symbol)` and adds sheets into it `(1m,3m,5m...)` and saves the file and then pulls the data from stock market api and saves into correct sheet. Such as ETH/BTC, create the file and sheets and pull "1m" data and save it into "1m" sheet.

Code creates file and sheets, I tested it.
The problem is after dataframe is written into excel file it deletes all other sheets. I tried to pull all data for each symbol. But when I opened the excel file only last `time frame (1w)` has been written and all other sheets are deleted. So please help.

I checked other problems but didn't find the same problem. At last part I am not trying to add a new sheet I am trying to save df to existed sheet.

```
#get_bars function pulls the data

def get_bars(symbol, interval):
.
.
.
return df
```

...

```
timeseries=['1m','3m','5m','15m','30m','1h','2h','4h','6h','12h','1d','1w']

from pandas import ExcelWriter
from openpyxl import load_workbook

for symbol in symbols:
    file = ('C:/Users/mi/Desktop/Kripto/' + symbol + '.xlsx')
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file)
    workbook.close()
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    for x in range(len(timeseries)):
        ws = wb.create_sheet(timeseries[x])
        print(wb.sheetnames)
        wb.save(file)
        workbook.close()
    xrpusdt = get_bars(symbol,interval='1m')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='xlsxwriter')
    xrpusdt.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='1m')
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of defining the `ExcelWriter` as a variable, you need to use it in a `With` statement and use the `append mode` since you have already created an excel file using `xlsxwriter` like below

```
for x in range(len(timeseries)): 
    xrpusdt = get_bars(symbol,interval=timeseries[x]) 
with pd.ExcelWriter(file,engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer: 
    xrpusdt.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=timeseries[x])
```

And in your code above, you're using a static interval as "1m" in the `xrpusdt` variable which is changed into variable in this code.

**Resources**:

**Pandas ExcelWriter**: here you can see the use-case of `append mode` 
 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter

**Pandas df.to_excel**: here you can see how to write to more than one sheet 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering so quick. I tried your solution. But it gave an error: `ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!` I searched this error and found a solution and added to ur code as:    `with pd.ExcelWriter(file,engine='openpyxl' mode='a') as writer:`          `xrpusdt.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='1m')` But with this line file is created and sheets are too but then another sheet named: "1m1" created and it has the Dataframe in it. Then I reviewed the codes again and deleted the :`for x in range(len(timeseries)):` loop entirely and rewrite it as like below:

Comment: `for x in range(len(timeseries)):`        `xrpusdt = get_bars(symbol,interval=timeseries[x])`    `with pd.ExcelWriter(file,engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:`        `xrpusdt.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=timeseries[x])` With these lines code creates file and appends new sheets named "1m","3m","5m","15m"... with dataframes in them. This works well for me. So thanks for showing the way. But still it is strange that I can't write a dataframe into an existed sheet in excel file. Thanks again. (sorry for not locating codes correctly, I am newbie in the site.)

Comment: Thank you @milikest. I've corrected the answer accordingly